# LFSR, different bits from different initial states

Tags: lfsr

Suppose we use an LFSR, which gives output $x_1x_2x_3\dots$ from some particular initial state. From another state, different from the previous one, using the same LFSR though, it gives sequence $y_1y_2y_3\dots$

Intuitively, some $i$ inequality must be true for $x_i\neq y_i$, but "intuitively" isn't exactly convincing, neither is "empirically."

Is it true that for some $i$ bits, the result will be different, i.e., $x_i\neq y_i$, and if so - why?

Comment: Hint: in a [Fibonnaci LFSR](http://www.newwaveinstruments.com/resources/articles/m_sequence_linear_feedback_shift_register_lfsr.htm), the bits of the initial state are also the first bits of the output; this makes it easy to prove the result for such LFSR. Then you can use the equivalence of Fibonnaci and Galois LFSRs to prove the result for the other kind.

Comment: But of course! Thanks.. it was too close to think about